# What's the difference between optimizer.compute_gradient() and tf.gradients() in tensorflow?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

The following code I've written, fails at `self.optimizer.compute_gradients(self.output,all_variables)`

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorlayer as tl
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
import numpy as np

class Network1():


def __init__(self):
    ops.reset_default_graph()
    tl.layers.clear_layers_name()

    self.sess = tf.Session()
    self.optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.1)

    self.input_x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 784],name="input")  

    input_layer = tl.layers.InputLayer(self.input_x)        

    relu1 = tl.layers.DenseLayer(input_layer, n_units=800, act = tf.nn.relu, name="relu1")
    relu2 = tl.layers.DenseLayer(relu1, n_units=500, act = tf.nn.relu, name="relu2")

    self.output = relu2.all_layers[-1]
    all_variables = relu2.all_layers

    self.gradient = self.optimizer.compute_gradients(self.output,all_variables)

    init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()
    self.sess.run(init_op)
```

with warning,

> TypeError: Argument is not a tf.Variable: Tensor("relu1/Relu:0",
>   shape=(?, 800), dtype=float32)

However when I change that line to `tf.gradients(self.output,all_variables)`, the code works fine, at least no warning is reported. Where did I miss, since I think these two methods are actually executing the same thing, that is return a list of (gradient, variable) pairs.

Comment: What is `tensorlayers`? We have `tf.contrib.layers`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`optimizer.compute_gradients` wraps [tf.gradients()](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_impl.py#L320), as you can see [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py#L281). It does additional asserts (which explains your error).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but why we need additional asserts?

Answer (score 5):

I would like to add to the above answer by referring to a simple point. `optimizer.compute_gradients` return a list of tuples as (grads, vars) pairs. Variables are always there, but the gradients might be None. That makes sense since computing the gradients of specific `loss` with respect to some of the variables in `var_list` can be `None`. It says there is no dependency.

On the other hand, `tf.gradients` only return the list of `sum(dy/dx)` for each variable. It MUST be accompanied by the variable list for applying the gradient update.

Henceforth, the following two approaches can be utilized interchangeably:

```
        ### Approach 1 ###
        variable_list = desired_list_of_variables
        gradients = optimizer.compute_gradients(loss,var_list=variable_list)
        optimizer.apply_gradients(gradients)

        # ### Approach 2 ###
        variable_list = desired_list_of_variables
        gradients = tf.gradients(loss, var_list=variable_list)
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, variable_list))
```